# How to sort objects by creation date to plug into high charts with Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, highcharts

I haven't worked with dashboards very much and am now working on creating a dashboard for my contest/giveaway app that I'm building with Meteor. I am using highcharts and am trying to figure out how exactly to structure my data so that the chart is updated in real time. Here is my ContestAnalytics.js file:

```
var category_arr = [moment().subtract(5, 'days').format('MMM D'), moment().subtract(4, 'days').format('MMM D'), moment().subtract(3, 'days').format('MMM D'), moment().subtract(2, 'days').format('MMM D'), moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('MMM D'), moment().format('MMM DD'), moment().add(1, 'days').format('MMM D'), moment().add(2, 'days').format('MMM D'), moment().add(3, 'days').format('MMM D'), moment().add(4, 'days').format('MMM D')  ];



function builtArea() {


  $('#container-area').highcharts({

    title: {
        text: 'Entries',
        x: -20 //center
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: category_arr
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Entries'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ''
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Entries',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3]
    }]
  });
}

Template.ContestAnalytics.rendered = function () {
   var currentContestId = this._id;
   var entriesCursor = Entries.find({contest_id: currentContestId});
   var entries = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

   entriesCursor.forEach(function(entry) {
      var m = moment(entry.submitted).format('MMM D');

      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         if (category_arr[i] === m) {
              entries[i] += 1;
         }
      }
   });

   builtArea(entries);
};
```

As you can see, I am using Moment.js to show a 10 day span on the x axis. I have hard coded values in the series data for the time being, but am trying to figure out how to make the series data dynamic.

I have an Entries collection that has contest_id and submitted attributes. The submitted attribute is populated at creation with `new Date()`. What I am hoping to do is plug an array into the series data that has 10 values. Each of the values will be a count of the number of entries that were created on a particular day. I'd appreciate any suggestions that you could offer on how to accomplish this.

You can find my repo here: https://github.com/ryanswapp/rymotion

EDIT

I just tried to make it work with the code in the rendered block and was unsuccessful. Any ideas why?

Comment: I advice you to  use a [datetime type](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type) of xAxis, it will be more comfortable instead of categories. So generally each of 10 values needs to be calculated in javascript or be pushed to separate series?

Comment: I'll have to give that a shot. Yes, I want the values to be dynamically added so they need to be calculated in javascript. My problem is that I'm not sure how to grab all the entries that were created within a particular date in order to push them into an array. Check my edit to see my most recent attempt.

Comment: In the series.data you have all your points.

Comment: Yes, that is true in this example. I played around with a bit more (after replacing the points in series.data with the dynamic entries) and still couldn't get it to work. I finally realized that it wasn't working because the value of ```this``` doesn't refer to the current contest within the template.render block like it does within the template.helper block. I am now trying to figure out how to dynamically grab the current contest id within the template.rendered block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In order to grab the id of the current template instance I had to use `Blaze.currentView._templateInstance.data._id` and then I could access all of the entries for a particular day that belonged to a particular contest.

```
Template.ContestAnalytics.rendered = function () {

  var currentContestId = Blaze.currentView._templateInstance.data._id;
  Tracker.autorun(function() {

      var entries = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          var tempNum = Entries.find({contest_id: currentContestId, submitted_day: category_arr[i] }).count();
          entries.push(tempNum);
      }
      builtArea(entries);

  });



};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use...

```
var firstSeries = Entries.find({submitted: category_arr[0]});
```

and then place that variable in your series...

```
data: [firstSeries]
```

Of course, if you go this route, you will need to set up a publication and a subscription so that your template has access to the Entries collection.

Comment: I just attempted what you proposed and was unable to get it working... See my edit. Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Can you link me to where you implemented the suggested change? I cannot find it in your repo. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/ryanswapp/rymotion/blob/master/app/client/templates/contests/contest_analytics/contest_analytics.js

Comment: I figured out my main problem... ```this``` in the template.rendered block doesn't refer to the current contest. I am not sure how to grab the current contest id from within template.rendered..